# How to overcome the bad effects of mother's curse?

Tags: dua, parents

When he was a child, a Muslim brother's mother would curse him when she was angry with him owing to his naughtiness with words like "May you always cry in your life," and other such strong curses. Today he is in his 40s and, though he is a very talented and hard-working man, he is unable to move out of a financial quagmire despite all efforts on his part. For the most part of his adult life he has been unhappy with little respite and has been beset by ongoing personal and financial problems almost ceaselessly.

In retrospect, he strongly feels that these circumstances came about owing to the curses of his mother, who loved him dearly but during momentary anger would curse him, and a mother's duas for her child, even if they are destructive, are accepted by Allah. Now his mother is no more and he desperately wants to overcome the ill effects of those curses but is unable to do so and his circumstances refuse to change. Is there a way out for him? Can someone please give an answer based on the strong references and evidences only?

Comment: One thing that amazes me is why parents persist in cursing their own children?? I recall a particularly heart-rending incident from a few years back. In a different city we had a neighbour and his wife told mine that one of her children was extremely boisterous but also the most beloved among them and she would keep cursing him "why don't you die" and, to cut a long story short, she eventually lost him. She told my wife that she carried his body in her arms for fifteen minutes holding his head close to her bosom after he died. She was crying uncontrollably while relating this to my wife.

Comment: @user5016 the grammar needs to be modified.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is a mother's curse real in Islam?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/76276/is-a-mothers-curse-real-in-islam)

Answer (score 1):

please have faith in Allah and understand that anything happening in our life is just a test for us !!

- There is nothing as a curse in Islam where someone would unintentionally curse someone else and ...! Allah has far more knowledge than what our limited minds may imagine!
- We can always ask Allah by means of Dua about things we want and Inshallah if Allah accepts it, then it will happen!

**So the Best solution for any trouble we have is just to ask it from Allah** and to accept his decision, we never know what's good for us! **Maybe** that financial problem of your friend is a blessing for him and if he gained lot's of money he would turn away from Allah.