# Is a mother's curse real in Islam?

Tags: dua, parents

I've been seeking for answer and asking some advice related to this problem, but I haven't found the answer yet. In my country, we are superstitious about the belief that if our biological mother is angry and talk something bad to their children i.e. cursing, the curse would turn out to be real.

I have this friend of mine and I want to help him to convince that curse is not real. He used to be a bad person, he said it himself, and when he was 14, he realised that Islam is the only religion he could devote to. He does his prayer 5 times a day without absence, He started to memorize Quran. And what it does matter is, he is always unlucky. He blames himself that once his mother ever cursed him and I don't want him to think that there's no hope anymore. I'm afraid if he wouldn't trust Islam anymore, because he's been very religious from what I could see.

What should he do? Is there any advice to help him? Quran or Hadith recitation related to this topic would be appreciated.

Comment: In Islam those who are allowed to be cursed and for which curses are real are disbelievers (as for believers the impact needs more details and must be discussed ). While cursing a believer is among the kaba'ir it is a big sin. The prophet () said in a sahih hadith compiled by both al-Bukhari and Muslim "**cursing a believer is like murdering him**".

Comment: @Medi1Saif Nice to know that, however some parents tend to get easily angry when their children are obstinate. If the parents mistakenly cursed their own children which are, of course believers, Would Allah forgive the children if they repent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Curse is real. Not just mother. Cursing in general is prohibited. You should advice your friend to avoid situations that might give an opportunity to be cursed.

> Jabir b. 'Abd Allah reported the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) as saying: Do
> not invoke curse on yourselves, and do not invoke curse on your
> children, and do not invoke curse on your servants, and do not invoke
> curse on your property, lest you happen to do it at a time when Allah
> is asked for something and grants your request. [Sunan Abi Dawud
> 1532](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/8/117)

Solution is increase in good deeds and ask Allah for forgiveness.

> Prophet Muhammad (ﷺ) said: “Have taqwa (fear) of Allah wherever you
> may be, and follow up a bad deed with a good deed which will wipe it
> out, and behave well towards the people.” - [Tirmidhi](https://sunnah.com/nawawi40:18)

Answer (score 2):

If a parent makes a dua for or against their children, then it is possible that it gets accepted and it is also possible that it gets rejected. The prophet ﷺ warned parents about making duas against their children:

> لا تدعوا على أنفسكم ولا تدعوا على أولادكم ولا تدعوا على أموالكم لا توافقوا من الله ساعة يسأل فيها عطاء فيستجيب لكم
>
> Do not pray against yourselves, do not pray against your children, and do not pray against your wealth, lest that coincide with an hour when Allah is asked and He answers your prayers.
>
> <sup>— [Muslim](https://ahadith.net/muslim/book/53/chapter/18/hadith/7515)</sup>

We can't really tell if a person's misfortune is because of the Dua or just coincidence or because of some other reason.

The solution is to seek forgiveness of Allah, and if possible forgiveness from the parent, and to give charity. Allah can do all things and it is not appropriate to lose hope of His Mercy:

> ولا تيأسوا من روح الله إنه لا ييأس من روح الله إلا القوم الكافرون
>
> Despair not of relief from Allah. Indeed, no one despairs of relief from Allah except the disbelieving people.
>
> <sup>— [Quran 12:87](https://quran.com/12/87?translations=20)</sup>